# How to convert SWF to uncompressed AVI?

Tags: video, conversion, avi, swf

Can someone explain how to convert `.`SWF files to uncompressed `.AVI` files. Which software I'd need or a tutorial I could use?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source file as `.FLA` and open them in Adobe Flash:

1. Go to: File > Export > **Export movie**
2. Choose **AVI** from the formats list
3. then you can tweak the export settings, where you can set the compression

This works on Windows only (not on a Mac).

Answer (score 0):

#### swf2avi

http://www.pizzinini.net/projects/swf2avi/

> swf2avi is a freeware tool to convert or batch-convert Flash movies (swf) to bitmaps, bitmap-sequences (bmp, jpg) or videos (avi).
>
> swf2avi supports all versions of Macromedia Flash. If a new release is available, install the Internet Explorer Plugin and use it with swf2avi.
>
> swf2avi supports all installed video codecs.

Comment: swf2avi does not support compressed swf files. FYI