# Are there any free .swf to avi converters?

Tags: video, avi, swf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SWF to uncompressed AVI](https://superuser.com/questions/54370/swf-to-uncompressed-avi)

Are there any free .swf to avi converters?

Comment: Duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/54370/swf-to-uncompressed-avi

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which Operating System you're using, however...

Look for a program called TranscoderRedux on the Mac.  It's a revival of the fantastic VisualHub utility that has since been discontinued.

It will also convert a lot of other formats as well.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/transcoderredux/

Comment: its windows vista..well i've got vista and xp....