# convert SWF to AVI on Linux

Tags: linux, avi, swf, video-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SWF to uncompressed AVI](https://superuser.com/questions/54370/swf-to-uncompressed-avi)

hello 
how i can convert SWF file to avi on linux ?

Answer (score 0):

> ffmpeg -i file.swf file.avi

Quality & codec settings are in "man ffmpeg".

Comment: this command does not convert

Comment: Is it really a swf video then?  Shockwave can be software too.